# Apache to Tomcat proxy what to do when i redirected to file not in proxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat

I have configured a proxy from `apache2` to `tomcat6` 
All working, plain and simple, but I have a problem when from my tomcat app I need to redirect to a JSP that is outside of the directory I configured with the `ProxyPass` directive.

This is what i have :

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass         /  http://127.22.22.1:8080/jsp/app/crm/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://127.22.22.1:8080/jsp/app/crm/
```

I need to redirect to a file that is `http://127.22.22.1:8080/ut/disable.jsp`
and when it redirects to it I'm getting :

```
/ut/disable.jsp?error=The%20user%20can't%20access%20the%20page HTTP/1.1" 404 1084
```

How can I enable other files from other directories to be proxied? just from within the `jsp/app/crm/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide clients with access to something hosted at `/ut/disable.jsp`, you're going to need to add the necessary `ProxyPass` directive.  For only that particular file:

```
ProxyPass /ut/disable.jsp http://127.22.22.1:8080/ut/disable.jsp
```

Or for the entire `/ut/` context:

```
ProxyPass /ut/ http://127.22.22.1:8080/ut/
```

Or you will have to modify your Tomcat application so that all URLs fall within the `/jsp/app/crm/` context.